# How to save TStringList with UNIX line endings?

Tags: delphi

I cannot figure how to save the lines of a TStringList using UNIX line endings (LF) instead of the default CRLF ones.

I've tried to use StringReplace() on the stringList.Text property without any success :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

StringList.Text is a property that generates the text every time. So when you assign the modified text back to the stringlist, you will undo you changes. When you get the text again, the stringlist will just build a new string with its default linebreak character.

This character can be influenced by setting the `LineBreak` property of the stringlist. 
The default value for `LineBreak` is the `sLineBreak` constant, which can be either `#13#10` on Windows or `#10` on Linux or `#13` on Mac.

Otherwise, if you save StringList.Text in a string variable, you can use `StringReplace` to change that string, or even better, use `AdjustLineBreaks`.

Comment: This would also affect TStringList.SaveToFile ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Good question! I haven't tried, but when I look into code,  `SaveToFile` calls `SaveToStream`, which calls `GetTextStr`. This is the same internal method that is used by the `Text` property. So, yes, this also affects `SaveToFile`.

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility is to use Jedi Code Library ( http://jcl.sf.net ) with split/join functionality in their version of string list.

```
var so : TJclStringList; // PODO style, requires finally-free-end
    si : iJclStringList; // ref-counted interface for method chaining (aka Fluent API style)
    s  : String;
...
    s := so.Join(^J);
    s := si.Join(^J);
```